# C# on Windows 7: Slow IP multicast sends?

Tags: c#, .net, multicast

I have an application that works well on Windows but seems to have become very slow on Windows 7.  I've tracked the problem to an unbound socket on which I do IP multicast sends, using "sendto".  These calls normally complete in ~1ms, but I'm seeing some completion times of 1s to 2s (yes, 1000x slower) on my windows 7 64-bit configuration.  My packets are fairly large and I've reconfigured the socket buffers accordingly.

In these particular tests I've had six applications running on my single laptop, forming a multicast group, and thus the multicast sends actually loop back and never need to go out on the wire.  I don't know if the issue arises with my apps on different machines; will test that case, but in even if the problem goes away in other configurations, I also need Isis2 to work this way.

Anyone ever seen anything like this before?

I'll be happy to share my code (this is part of the Isis2 system, available for free download from Cornell at http://www.cs.cornell.edu/ken/isis2) but I don't have a 2 line demo of the problem.  However, I will say that this part of Isis2 is pretty mature by now and has been multicasting happily for 3 years or so as I've extended and worked with the library.  As noted, I'm suspicious that this may be a windows 7 issue.

I never see the issue with small packets so it definitely has something to do with my sending large ones.

Comment: I can promise, though, that if one of you has a good insight for me here I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: Ken, if you do end up finding the answer outside of the site, feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted. The information could be useful to someone else in the future too!

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll do that.  The very old threads are marked closed now, so I can't do it retroactively.  Kind of a shame because in fact your point is dead on.

Comment: "I never see the issue with small packets so it definitely has something to do with my sending large ones."  How big are your "large" ones?

Comment: Bengie, it varies but in this case I was setting the send and receive buffer sizes to 32kbytes

Comment: @Ken Birman: While fragmentation will happen, I don't think a 32KB packet would hurt. NIC driver issues by chance? Can you test your app on other machines?  BTW, IPv6 will not allow fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks for the IPv6 pointer.  Heading into work now and can test the identical thing from there.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Benjie may be correct about the NIC suggestion.  I tried it on two other machines and the same code ran without problems.  Here on my Apple Mac running Windows, gets "stuck"... very curious.  So, Benjie, now that I can confirm that it could be the NIC, do you have any idea what I should be looking at?  It must be something I'm doing...  In fact the Mac acts strange in another way too: bursts of IPMC traffic cause my VPN session to break.  So clearly the NIC does get involved in some ways during these runs, even with all the receivers on a single machine.

For the time being I've worked around this by setting the TTL value to 0 when doing experiments confined to my single Windows platform running on the Mac.  This has the added benefit that I don't end up doing a DDoS attack on my Internet radio and television downstairs.  But I am curious and would love to understand what could possibly cause a 2s delay when doing IPMC wirelessly within my house!

Anyhow, thanks Benjie.  Good idea.